# Where did the second term in the third line come from?

Tags: general-relativity

2[image]

Where did the second term in the third line come from? This is the relativistic action of a slow moving particle, with $u^{μ}≈(1,0,0,0)$ in semi flat space $g_{μυ}=η_{μυ}+h_{μυ}$.

Comment: Conventionally latin indices sum over only the spatial components 1 to 3, so line 3 is just the sum in line 2 split into temporal and spatial parts. You don't say what $h$ is. Is this linearised gravity i.e. $g = \eta + h$?

Comment: Yes it is the linear gravity

Comment: What about the second term in the second line, doesn't look like it follows from the division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The third line follows from the second if you note that $x^0 = t$ and the $x^i$ coordinates are just your spatial coordinates;  so $dx^0/dt = 1$ and $dx^i/dt = v^i$.  Specifically,
  $$
  g_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{dt} \frac{dx^\beta}{dt} = g_{00} \frac{dx^0}{dt} \frac{dx^0}{dt} + g_{0i} \frac{dx^0}{dt} \frac{dx^i}{dt} + g_{i0} \frac{dx^i}{dt} \frac{dx^0}{dt} + g_{ij} \frac{dx^i}{dt} \frac{dx^j}{dt} \\
  = g_{00} + 2 g_{0i} v^i + g_{ij} v^i v^j.
  $$
- The fourth line follows from the third by substituting $g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$ everywhere, and noting that $\eta_{0i} = 0$.
- The fifth line follows from the fourth because we are (presumably) in the Newtonian limit where spacetime is nearly flat ($h$ is "small") and velocities are much less than $c$ ($v^i$ is "small".)  In this limit, the third and fifth terms in the square root are negligible compared to other terms under the square root, and so we can discard them.